# What syntax language is used in the Pipeline expression builder in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can anyone tell me what syntax language is used in the Pipeline expression builder in Azure data factory?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its called expression language. The code in expression language starts with `@` symbol.
From your error image, it seems you are writing expression incorrectly.

`pipeline().RunId` gets you run id of your pipeline. after this immediately you are again writing expression `pipeline().Groupid()`. That should not the way to write.

From the expression what you written, it seems you want to generate a string which contains `pipeline run id` and `pipeline group id` as values with brackets. Please use below code for same.

```
@string(createArray(pipeline().RunId,pipeline().GroupId))
```